# Conditional transitive dependencies inclusion with maven

Tags: java, maven

My goal is to include one project into another while controlling the transitive dependencies that should be included.

Let's say that Project Y is based upon Project X.
Project X has two defined profiles, profile-a and profile-b:

```
<project>
  ...
  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>profile-a</id>
      <dependencies>
          // [A] depednencies
      </dependencies>
    </profile>
    <profile>
      <id>profile-b</id>
      <dependencies>
          // [B] depednencies
      </dependencies>
    </profile>
  <profiles>
</project>
```

Is there a way to include project X into project Y with the possibility of specifying the profile with which we want to import project X?

A sample way to control transitive dependencies should be the use of dependencies exclusion, but I'm looking for a more sophisticated method if ever it is possible to use one.

---

I have a second question that concerns the use of dependencies in profiles:
Naturally, project X may have many classes that depend on both dependencies of profile-a and profile-b.

If project X is built or imported (if ever it is possible) with one profile, this won't break the compilation of classes that use the dependencies of the other profile?

Thank you all for your feedback.

Comment: Sounds weird. Dependencies should never being handled via profiles. If you need having different dependencies for whatever reason you should make separate modules of it...the important questions is: Why do you need such thing?

Comment: I wasn't sure neither about the consistency of this approach. I used the example of profiles just to give an idea about what I want to achieve...I have a project that offers many utilities classes; To control the amount of libraries that will be loaded in the final application, I just wanted to know if there is a solution to lighten the loaded libraries and include only what is needed.

Comment: It's not clear what kind of application you are working on...Can you elaborate a little bit more ...

Comment: I have a project on which many utilities classes are gathered. Sometimes these classes achieve the same goal but with different frameworks. For example, for unit testing we can prepare base classes based on either JUnit, TestNG or any other unit testing framework...Based on which testing framework we want to use in our final application, the objectif is to import only the dependency of this framework and ignore the others...Now the question is: is it a good idea to assemble all the libraries in this one utility project, or must we use different modules as you stated in your first reply?

Comment: Based on what you explained i receive the impression to have separated modules. Say for example one like `xx-test-junit`, `xx-test-testng` etc.

Comment: I thought about separated modules too, but I was at the same time wondering if there is an automated way to prepare one module with all the utilities classes and then import just what is needed in the targeted application...If it is not possible, then separated modules remains the only solution for my case

Answer (score 0):

After my discussion with @khmarbaise I made an additional search in maven website, and I stumbled upon [this article](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-using-one-source-directory.html).

In this page, there is a paragraph that concerns **Producing Multiple Unique JARs from a Single Source Directory**, where it is specified:

> As many people that complain about not being able to spread out their
>   sources into multiple source directories seem to complain about not
>   wanting to spread anything out, producing several unique artifacts
>   from a single directory using includes and excludes.
>
> **Why isn't this recommended?**
>
> This practice can be confusing and risky.
>
> You may end up building two JARs that include the same classes - this
>   indicates that the common functionality should have been abstracted
>   into a separate dependency. You may end up introducing a dependency
>   between the two JARs that you didn't realise, and often a circular
>   dependency. This indicates that the classes are in the wrong JAR, or
>   perhaps that everything should just be a single JAR.
>
> **How do I do this?**
>
> You still should adhere to producing one artifact per POM, but this
>   requires having multiple POMs, and hence multiple subdirectories. The
>   positive to this is that these introduced directories won't change the
>   layout of existing code, and will establish a future layout should you
>   decide to separate.

At first, I was looking for a way to manage transitive dependencies from a project to another by creating many artifacts from the same source.

After this reading, it is clear that maven encourages the creation of one artifact per pom.

Creating separate modules of the project surely remains the most clean way to handle different cases of dependencies usage from one project to another.